# Problems understanding the use of shared_ptr<void> in std::map

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, stdmap

I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

typedef std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<void>> M;
typedef std::vector<std::string> S;

void build_word_tree_from_sentences(const S& sentence_list, M& root)
{
    for (const auto& sentence : sentence_list)
    {
        std::string word;
        std::stringstream ss(sentence);
        M* base = &root;
        while (ss >> word)
        {
            auto found = base->find(word);
            if (found == base->end())
            {
                base->insert(std::make_pair(word, std::make_shared<M>()));
            }

            auto b = base->find(word)->second;
            base = std::static_pointer_cast<M>(b).get();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    S sentence_list = {"Hello word", "Hello there"};
    M tree;
    build_word_tree_from_sentences(sentence_list, tree);
}
```

I would like to have a help in understanding the use of the `std::shared_ptr` in the map `M`.
When inserting a new element, if not already present, in the map:

```cpp
base->insert(std::make_pair(word, std::make_shared<M>()));
```

The `std::shared_ptr` is called with an empty argument, this is also confusing me.

Answer (score 3):

Your question requires to study some features of `std::shared_ptr` before coming to an answer.

[std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is a smart pointer that retains shared ownership of an object through a pointer. Several `std::shared_ptr` objects may own the same object. The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when either of the following happens:

- the last remaining `std::shared_ptr` owning the object is destroyed;
- the last remaining `std::shared_ptr` owning the object is assigned to another pointer.

The fundamental idea of this and other smart pointers is to allow the client to use them as if they were native pointers, but providing the additional feature of automatic memory management. In particular, they exploit [SBRM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).

This mechanism is extremely useful for containers, since they work with objects of `value_type` and not with eventually external storages that are referenced by the objects. For example, in erase operations, the container destroys the object (in this case, the entire node that contains the object is destroyed and then deallocated). If a native pointer were used to reference an external object, as the pointer is destroyed, the external storage would consequently not be deallocated, leading to a memory leak. Among other things, using a native pointer would not make possible to share resources between different containers as in the case of `std::shared_ptr`.

Since the object deletion procedure is type-erased, `std::shared_ptr` can be specialized for the incomplete type `void`, which allows the client to refer to any object in the same way as it would be done with a native pointer `void*`.

Calling the [std::make_shared()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) function allocates a value-initialized object of specialized type, which is `M`. In particular, the function offers a small advantage in terms of performance and space usage as it allocates memory for the reference counter together with the object.

I believe the code was developed to create a `std::map` that contains objects of type `std::map` in order to create a tree whose nodes are trees themselves and so on. However, the definition of the `mapped_type` of a `std::map` specialization as the specialization itself would have led to a recursion.

```cpp
using M = std::map<std::string, M>>; // Error!
```

Thus, it is necessary to define the `mapped_type` as a void pointer, which can reference to an object of type `M` without the need of defining it. Although the use of `std::shared_ptr` may seem inappropriate, since resource sharing never occurs in the piece of code, it had likely been preferred as `std::unique_ptr` requires more attention in order to be used with `void`.